# Which 2nd root finding method does the HP32E use to compute $Q^{-1}$?

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, algorithms, normal-distribution, computational-mathematics

The ancient pocket calculator [HP32E](https://www.hpmuseum.org/hp32.htm) computes $Q$, areas under the normal curve, with the ["Algorithm 39"](https://doi.org/10.1093/comjnl/12.2.197) (same in [FORTRAN](https://doi.org/10.2307/2346800)) and the inverse $Q^{-1}$, quantile, using two different root finder. One is Newton's method, for the other I lack the *know-why*. I compared with Halley's method, with Householder's method, others, alas -- no match.

**Details**: By analysing the trace log of an emulated calculator (running the original firmware) I found, both functions, $Q$ and $Q^{-1}$, are divided in three sections using different formulas/procedures. Due to the symetry of the functions the outer sections use the same formula/procedure and adjust the result accordingly. For the middle section of $Q^{-1}$ Newton's method is used, while the algorithm for section I (and III) goes like this:

*Setup of iteration*

$m = \sqrt {-\mathrm{ln}\left (x^2\right )}$

$\displaystyle n = m - \frac{6,1}{\displaystyle 13 + m - \frac{94}{m + 8}}$,
what is (for $x \lt -1$) almost the [asymptotic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Quantile_function) $-\sqrt {\mathrm{ln} \frac{1}{x^2} - \mathrm{ln}\mathrm{ln} \frac{1}{x^2} - \mathrm{ln}(2\pi)}+o(1)$

$z_0 = n$, the initial guess, see *note* below after question

$h_0 = e^{\displaystyle n^2/2}$

*The iteration*

Do $i = 1$ by 1 until abs($k_i) <$ 1E-10

$r_i = Q(z_{i-1})$   using [Q part 2](https://forum.hp41.org/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=427) as found in a. m. "Algorithm 39"

$s_i = 1/(z_{i-1} + b_2 + r_{i})$   with $b_2$ same as in *Q part 2*

$t_i = x \cdot {h_{i-1}}/{a_1}$   with $a_1 = 0,398942280444$ (what is almost $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$)

$k_i = z_{i-1}(t_i - s_i)$   what is   $\displaystyle \sqrt{2\pi}\cdot h \cdot z \cdot (x-Q(z))$

$h_i = h_{i-1}/(1 + k_i)$  
to apply the correction this way differs from Newton's method,
            while for small $k$ it's quite close to the Taylor series.

$z_i = \sqrt{2 \mathrm{ln}(h_i)}$   what is   $\sqrt{z^2-2 \mathrm{ln}(1+k)}$
*loop/iterate/repeat*

**Question**: What root finding method is this? Looking here and there for quite some time now, I found nothing similar yet.
Why I ask? I just like to grasp the math behind it.

*Note*: A detail nice to know, insignificant regarding my question. The HP32E sets the initial guess $z_0=\displaystyle n^2/2$ instead of $n$ as shown above. No doubt an error (IMO), which is ironed out by 1..2 more iterations.

Urged by the hint in the comment *(links can rot away over time)* here the formula "Q part 2" referenced above:
[image: Q part 2]
I documented it according the found procedure *before* I knew about its origin in "Algorithm 39".
Note, $t=x^2/2$

**Some supplement**: (mostly guesswork as I am not a mathematician)
My reasoning about the a. m. factor $\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot h \cdot z$ goes like this:
Comparing with Newton's method where the correction to $x_i$ is
$\frac{-\mathrm{f}(x_i)}{\mathrm{f'}(x_i)}$, the factor here must be deduced similarly.
In $\sqrt{z^2-2\,\mathrm{ln}(1+k)}$ the correction $k$ comprises $Q$ in some way, so this is the function which will with its derivative make the "funny factor" $\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot h \cdot z$

First, Q expressed by erf (error function):
$Q = \frac{\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+1}{2}$

The iterated function, with (regarding the derivative) $k$ *simplified* to $k = Q$:
$\sqrt{z^2-2\,\mathrm{ln}(1+Q)}$

The reciprocal of its derivative (I got using [Reduce CAS](http://www.reduce-algebra.com))
$\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}\sqrt{-2\ln\left(\frac{\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+3}{2}\right)+z^2}
\sqrt{2\pi}\left(-\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-3\right)$

Simplified by `let {sqrt(z^2-2*log(1 + Q)) => z, e^(x^2/2) => h};` results in
$\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot h \cdot z \cdot\frac{\left(-\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-3\right)}{2}$
so here shows the "funny factor", alas, next step, final amelioration using the initial "Q by erf"
results in:
$$-\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot h \cdot z \cdot \left(Q+1\right)$$

So with few simplifications I get a formula with wrong sign and with $Q+1$ instead of $Q$. In addition, my "proof" is based on a step of the procedure I found analysing the HP32E, forming it back and forth to find the factor found in another step, kind of circular reasoning, I doubt, even if it looks nice.

Comment: So $b_{2} = -3.8052 \cdot 10^{-8}$? Is this some "magic constant" or is it known where this number comes from?

Comment: Yes, correct. This constant comes from ["Algorithm 39"](https://doi.org/10.1093/comjnl/12.2.197), to call it $b_2$ is my idea when I showed it as formula [Q part 2](https://forum.hp41.org/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=427)

Comment: References (as links or otherwise) are appreciated but it is much preferred when questions are *self-contained* (links can rot away over time). This use of $b_{2}$ does not make sense to me. If this were IEEE-754 single-precision computation, one might consider a rounding constant of sorts, possibly to keep errors one-sided, but his is 10-digit decimal computation from what I understand.

Comment: There are two more exceptional factors, two pettily different versions of the constant $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, 0,398942280444 and 0,398942280385. Probably to get correct results to the last digit.  
Yes, numbers on the HP32E have a 10-digit mantissa **for the user**, internaly the exponent is saved in another register what enables computing with 13 digits. Results for the user are rounded.

Comment: Please don't use "Edit:".  Instead, revise your question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.  Please don't put meta-questions, like asking how to ask on Stats.SE, in your question.  Please ask only a single question per post, and make it clear what your question is.

Comment: I revised my query according to your hint and removed all **edit** in the hope any content manager is happy now.